# Wrong git branch is being referenced during program run

Tags: git, git-branch

I have 2 folders: **mcell** and **mcell_tools**.

```
/mcell$ git branch -a
  master
* mcell4_mdl2datamodel
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/binary_reaction_output
  ...
  remotes/origin/mcell4_mdl2datamodel
  ...


/mcell_tools$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/development
  remotes/origin/master
```

Both of these folders are checked out on their appropriate (though different) branches, as you can see above indicated by the *.

**Problem:** 
I have a program inside **mcell_tools** that calls a file inside **mcell**, which outputs text into the terminal. My problem is that for some reason the file inside **mcell** is being called as if **mcell** was checked out on the *master* branch, not the *mcell4_mdl2datamodel* branch that I want it to be on.

I'm not very experienced with git, so I might be missing something obvious, but it seems to me that because my program inside **mcell_tools** is checked out on the *master* branch, the file that it calls from the **mcell** folder is automatically configured into it's *master* branch as well, instead of the *mcell4_mdl2datamodel* branch that it says it's in. This seems absurd, so I must be missing something.

To clarify, there is nowhere in the **mcell_tools** program that checks its own branch in order to determine the branch of all other files it calls. I know this because I've been able to run different branches from this program in the past when I was using my machine at work (instead of my home setup).

I know that the **mcell** file is running in it's *master* configuration instead of the desired *mcell4_mdl2datamodel* because of the terminal output it produces.

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by "I have a file inside mcell_tools that calls a file inside mcell". For example, if this file uses the output of git branch to work out its branch, and it does that while in a directory within mcell_tools, it will see master.

Comment: Thanks. I've changed my description a bit, and added another paragraph to explain that the mcell_tools program doesn't check its own branch to determine the branch of other files it calls.

Comment: A [mcve] would help a lot with diagnosing this.